# Custom User Registration: How to write gender to customer record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

My user registration form has a custom field for `Gender`. How can I make SCA write the customer's gender to the NS database?

Should I use Commerce API or SuiteScript API?

I guess I should edit the model `Account/SuiteScript/Account.Model.js` but should I use the Commerce API (`Customer` object or the `Profile`/`User` object) or directly write to the database using `record.setFieldValue()`?

In `Account/SuiteScript/Account.Model::register()` function:

```
//@method register
//@param {UserData} user_data
//@param {Account.Model.Attributes} user_data
register: function (user_data)
{
    var customer = session.getCustomer();

    ....default user registration code

    var user = Profile.get();



    // Should I do it like this?
    customer.updateProfile({
        "customfields": {
            "custentity_dev_gender": user_data.gender
        }
    })

    // Should I edit the user object??

    // Should I interact directly with the customer record. Does Commerce API allow this??
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', user.id);
    record.setFieldValue('custentity_dev_gender', user_data.gender);
    var internalId = nlapiSubmitRecord(record);



    return {
        touchpoints: session.getSiteSettings(['touchpoints']).touchpoints
    ,   user: user
    ,   cart: LiveOrder.get()
    ,   address: Address.list()
    ,   creditcard: CreditCard.list()
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you tried my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Its Very Simple actually no need to write `record.setFieldValue()`

1. Very first step is to create custom entity field from Customization--> Entity Field-->New
2. Apply the entity field to customer give edit access to field and Save.
3. Copy the entity id from there, in this case say 'custentity_gender_field'
4. The you need to override below two files, if you don't know ask separate question I'll reply there.

i.Modules/suitecommerce/LoginRegister@2.2.0/Templates/login_register_register.tpl
 ii.Modules/suitecommerce/Profile@2.3.0/SuiteScript/Profile.Model.js

5. Go to first file write below code somewhere where you need to put gender

```html
<div class="login-register-register-form-controls-group" data validation="control-group">
 <label class="login-register-register-form-label for="custentity_gender_field">{{translate 'Gender: '}}
  <small class="login-register-register-form-optional">{{translate '(optional)'}}</small>
 </label>
 <div class="login-register-register-form-controls" data-validation="control">
  <input type="text" name="custentity_gender_field" id="custentity_gender_field" class="login-register-register-form-input">
 </div>
</div>
```

6. Then Go to Second File i.e. Profile.Model.js

You can see in get function various filed values, put your custom field value there

```
this.fields = this.fields || ['isperson', 'email', 'internalid', 'name', 'overduebalance', 'phoneinfo', 'companyname', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'middlename', 'custentity_gender_field', 'emailsubscribe', 'campaignsubscriptions', 'paymentterms', 'creditlimit', 'balance', 'creditholdoverride'];
```

7. Deploy your code and test under user roles--> Manage User

I missed one more thing here, you need to make changes in

Account@2.2.0/SuiteScript/Account.Model.js as well  in this model find

```
register: function (user_data)
{

}
```

and your custom field in

```
ModelsInit.session.registerCustomer(
{ 
    custentity_gender_field:user_data.custentity_gender_field
});
```

That's it...

Comment: If you are done with my solution you can mark my ans